# Loading a webpart inside of another webpart dynamically

Tags: sharepoint-online, web-part, spfx, spfx-webparts

I have a specific requirement to implement dynamic web-part loading.

What I am trying to achieve is to have a web-part basically load inside of another. Not sure if this is possible or where to start.

I am currently running SharePoint Online.

If anyone could point me into the right direction, it would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible:
https://www.techmikael.com/2018/06/dynamically-load-web-part-from-another.html
In short - you need to instantiate ClientSideWebPartManager from @microsoft/sp-webpart-base and use it to load and place webparts.

Edit. Ops looks like there is no ClientSideWebPartManager in @microsoft/sp-webpart-base export... But I suppose it is possible to still get it from there...